# simple 6-line bash script while loop... WHAT is wrong?

Tags: bash, unix, loops, while-loop

I have a TSV file that looks like:

```
input.tsv
Apple       Give me an iPad. 
Apple       I love MacBookPro!
Google      Buy the Nexus.
Google      Chromebooks are easy to use.
Microsoft   Surface is awesome.
```

First column is one word, second column is a sentence.  I just want my output to look like

```
apple.txt
Give me an iPad.
I love the MacBook Pro!

google.txt
Buy the Nexus.
Chromebooks are easy to use.
```

This is my script:

```
while read -r company sentence
do
    for line in $sentence
    do
        printf "$line\n" >> $company.txt
    done
done < input.tsv
```

But the output is tokenizing one word per line like:

```
apple.txt
Give
me
an
iPad
```

I can't figure out what's wrong!!! Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while read` loop is already getting the whole line, so I'm not sure what the intent of the `for` loop is.  You're looping over the words and outputting one per line.

Also, your `printf` is not safe if the line has percent signs or backslashes in it.

```
while read -r company sentence; do
  printf '%s\n' "$sentence" >>"$company.txt"
done < input.tsv
```

Also also, most Unixy file systems are case-sensitive (the default on OS X being one notable exception); as written, this will create files `Apple.txt` and `Google.txt` instead of `apple.txt` and `google.txt`.  If you want lowercase filenames, then you need to change the target of that append redirect a bit.

If you're in bash 4, you can just replace `"$company.txt"` with `"${company,,}.txt"`.  In older bash versions, you can do `>>"$(tr A-Z a-z <<<"$company").txt"` or similar.

Comment: even easier to lowercase: `declare -l company` and let bash do the case conversion for you.

Comment: @glennjackman true, but bash is also doing the case conversion in the `${company,,}` expression, just at expansion time instead of read time.  :)  You certainly could do the `declare` instead if you're using bash 4.  With bash 3 (Hey, Apple!  Upgrade already!), you're still stuck with something like that `tr` call.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `for line in $sentence`? (make it even smaller!)

```
while read -r company sentence
do
    printf '%s\n' "$sentence" >> $company.txt
done < input.tsv
```

Comment: Whups, you were faster than me.  But you should use `printf '%s\n' "$sentence"` instead of `printf "$sentence\n"`.

Comment: Hehe, I just let that, be s4ldomly use `printf`. If up to me, I'd make it an even simpler `echo "$sentence" >> $company.txt`

Comment: This works!! Mark, what's the difference between printf '%s\n' "$sentence" and just simply printf "$sentence" ?

Comment: First argument is the format (which can contain normal text), the rest are arguments. If there's data in your `$sentence` that is 'special' in a format string, (`%s`, literal `\n`'s etc.) they will be interpreted rather then stored as-is.

Comment: Using bare `echo` would work in almost all cases, but there are still some pathological cases (such as `$sentence` equal to `-n`. :)) Using `printf` with an explicit format string is the safest general solution.